# How do I apply URL normalization rules in PHP?

Tags: php, url, normalization

Is there a pre-existing function or class for URL normalization in PHP?

Specifically, following the semantic preserving normalization rules laid out in this [wikipedia article on URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization), (or whatever 'standard' I should be following).

- Converting the scheme and host to lower case
- Capitalizing letters in escape sequences
- Adding trailing / (to directories, not files)
- Removing the default port
- Removing dot-segments

Right now, I'm thinking that I'll just use `parse_url()`, and apply the rules individually, but I'd prefer to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @yc : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+seo+url

Comment: @ajreal no, not `<link rel="canonical"...>`. Just, normalizing a URL for, for example, requesting data about it from an API, particularly those that require that the URL be hashed, and so if you don't use a normalized URL, you'll get inaccurate or no results.

Comment: @yc : what is the diff between `http://stackoverflow.com` and `http://stackoverflow.com//` ? can u provide more example of url u try to avoid ?

Comment: Huge difference! The former hashes (md5) as 57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a, the latter hashes as 8b34e6ecb6898f39350c1264d6d7aa6c. As far as I'm concerned, they're different URLs, even though a server will resolve the difference. There's a standard, as linked to, that seeks to create normalized URLs. I'm not inventing a concept here; there's a whole wiki article dedicated to the phenomenon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pear Net_URL2 library looks like it'll do at least part of what you want.  It'll remove dot segments, fix capitalization and get rid of the default port:

```
include("Net/URL2.php");
$url = new Net_URL2('HTTP://example.com:80/a/../b/c');
print $url->getNormalizedURL();
```

emits:

```
http://example.com/b/c
```

I doubt there's a general purpose mechanism for adding trailing slashes to directories because you need a way to map urls to directories which is challenging to do in a generic way.  But it's close.

References:

- http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2
- http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/docs/latest/Net_URL2/Net_URL2.html