# Filtering links based on whether already seen

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

I'm building a simple web crawler and I'm trying to filter links based on whether or not they've been seen before. The issue is that a link might be the same, but with a forward slash, arguments. I also would like to filter out mail to's. Is there any known, straightforward to do this? I'm currently working in pHp.

Edit:
I used Net_URL2.php to normalize the URL's after viewing this:
[How do I apply URL normalization rules in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175630/how-do-i-apply-url-normalization-rules-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, there's no straight way to do that. Have a read at [this article about URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) to find out some reasons why that is hard to accomplish.

Comment: Did not know the technical term. Found this as a result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175630/how-do-i-apply-url-normalization-rules-in-php. Works, for now.